# The jQuery method 'hasClass' works fine in FF but not in chrome

Tags: jquery

I'm working with the foundation framework and use the orbit slider, I created a method for getting the actual shown slide index of the slide show. In firefox everything works fine and the function returns the correct actual slide index, but in Chrome it returns '-1', although the HTML code includes the requested element.

```
// function for getting the actual slide index of a slide show
function getActualSlideIndex(){
    $counter = 0;
       $( '#featured1 > li' ).each(function (){
           console.log($( this ));
           if ($(this).hasClass('active')){
               return $counter;
           }
          $counter++; 
       });
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: Please reproduce it on jsfiddle

Comment: I highly doubt it's returning the correct index in Firefox. It should always return -1, on any browser. Can you make a fiddle please with the relevant code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be simplified to

```
function getActualSlideIndex() {
    var index = $('#featured1 > li.active').index();
    return index == -1 ? -1 : index + 1;
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/w98Yk/)

Answer (score 1):

Your `return $counter` returns from the internal callback you pass to `each`, not from the external function. You probably want this :

```
// function for getting the actual slide index of a slide show
function getActualSlideIndex(){
      $counter = 0;
       $( '#featured1 > li' ).each(function (){
           if ($(this).hasClass('active')){
               return false;
           }
          $counter++; 
       });
      return $counter || -1;
}
```

Comment: return false stops everything after it right? I think just a return should exit the function.

Comment: The "return false" inside the `.each()` is meaningless, better optimize the code if you go this way.

Comment: The function always exits. Returning false prevents the next iteration (and thus prevents the counter from being incremented).